# Pelican - How to remove .html extension on local host

Tags: python, static-site, pelican

I have a pelican blog and I want to remove the .html extension from the URL. I added the following to pelicanconf.py

```
ARTICLE_URL ='{slug}'
PAGE_URL = '{slug}'
```

The problem is that `invoke livereload` doesn't serve the urls without html extension. `pelican --autoreload --listen` does, but it doesn't automatically refresh my browser on changes.

Any solution to enjoy the best of both worlds?

Comment: What are you using to host the blog? It might be easier to rewrite the URL and remove .html rather than enforce the behaviour natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `*_URL` and `*_SAVE_AS` configuration options.

E.g.:

```py
ARTICLE_URL = '{slug}/'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = '{slug}/index.html'
PAGE_URL = '{slug}/'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = '{slug}/index.html'
```

The above does rely on the fact that webservers will provide the "index.html" file when you attempt to browse a directory directly, but this is near-universal behaviour.

You can do the above for any `*_URL` setting. Further example:

```py
CATEGORY_URL = "category/{slug}/"
CATEGORY_SAVE_AS = "category/{slug}/index.html"
CATEGORIES_URL = "category/"
CATEGORIES_SAVE_AS = "category/index.html"
```